# Fetching proper data in flutter app from djano-rest

Tags: django, api, http, django-rest-framework, flutter

Here I'm creating a moblie app with flutter. Also I've created the back-end with django rest framework. And now I want to use the informations on my back-end in the flutter.
For Registration, I can post my user info from flutter to django rest, It works proberly. But when some of inputs are incorrect I don't know how to reflect the problem form back-end into the flutter app.

For example here, the email address is incorrect:

[image]

And this is my code for fetching and getting data:

```
void _postmessage(
    {@required var username,
    @required var email,
    @required var password1,
    @required var password2}) async {
  var url = 'url';
  var data = {
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "password1": password1,
    "password2": password2
  };
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);
  ioClient.post(url, body: data);
  _fetchdata();
}

_fetchdata() async {
  List list = List();
  final response = await http.get('url');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    print(list);
  } else {
    // list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    print(json.decode(response.body));
  }
}
```

As the result I get this in the output:

[image]

It's printing this on the output:
flutter: {detail: Method "GET" not allowed.}

Comment: can you provide your rest API endpoint and data which it accepts. (Also one more thing you can try POST method as you API clearly Specifying GET method not allowed)

Comment: did you figure this out? how do you authenticate with Django?

Answer (score 0):

final response = await http.post('url');